# Sails JS passport http 401

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, sails.js, passport.js

I'm trying to secure my sails js rest api with the help of the passport http package but at the moment I can't figure out where the error is in my code. 
I used this [repo](https://gist.github.com/mbjordan/9547591) and this [tutorial](http://scottksmith.com/blog/2014/05/29/beer-locker-building-a-restful-api-with-node-passport/) to get an idea of how this should work. My problem is that my code always returns a 401.
I don't really know where to look for the error. If you need more information about my code just comment.
Bruno

**EDIT:**
I found the source of the problem (With the help of @Viktor). I just didn't really understood how HTTP-Basic authentication works. Now the problem is how do I send my auth-credentials and my data? If I just test the routes with auth(...), they work... But how do I add the data? Or do I have to authenticate me first and send the data in the second request?

**passport.js**

```
var passport = require('passport');
var BasicStrategy = require('passport-http').BasicStrategy;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findOne({
    id: id
  }, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use('user-authentication', new BasicStrategy(
  function(mail, password, done) {
    sails.log.error("hallo");
    User.findOne({
      mail: mail
    }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }

      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, {
          message: 'Incorrect email.'
        });
      }

      // Make sure the password is correct
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }

        // Password did not match
        if (!isMatch) {
          return done(null, false, {
            message: 'Invalid Password'
          });
        }

        // Success
        return done(null, user);
      });
    });
  }
));
```

**isAuthenticated.js**

```
var passport = require("passport");


module.exports = function (req, res, ok) {
    passport.authenticate("user-authentication", {
        session: false
    }, function (err, user, info) {
        if (err || !user) {
            res.set("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"Restricted\"");

            return res.send("You are not permitted to perform this action", 401);
        }

        req.session.user = user;
        return ok(null, user);

    })(req, res, ok);
};
```

**policies.js**

```
module.exports.policies = {
  '*': true,

  'UserController': {
    update: 'isAuthenticated'
  }
}
```

**UserController.test.js**

```
var request = require('supertest');
var async = require('async');

describe('UserController', function() {

  describe('#new()', function() {
    it('...', function (done) {
      request(sails.hooks.http.app)
      .post('/user/new')
      .send({ own_number: '654122', password: 'test', mail: 'test@test.com', device_id: '1234', numbers: [1234567] })
      .expect(200)
      .end(done);
    });
  });

  describe('#update()', function(){
    it('...', function (done) {
      async.series([

        function(callback){
          request(sails.hooks.http.app)
          .post('/contact/update')
          .send({ number: 1234, mail: "test@test.com", password: "test" })
          .expect(200)
          .end(callback);
        },

        function(callback){
          request(sails.hooks.http.app)
          .post('/user/update')
          .send({ numbers: [1234], mail: "tet@test.com", password: "test" })
          .expect(200)
          .end(callback);
        }
      ], done);
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: Try to use "Basic" instead of user-authentication

Comment: Ok but I thought I can name the different strategies

Comment: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me – I'm able to authenticate as well as access and manage the user data once there's a valid user in the database. With an empty user database, you would get `401` all the time, of course, as these policies don't allow you to create even the first user to authenticate as. Temporarily disabling the `UserController` policies in `config/policies.js` gives you the opportunity to create the first user.

Assuming you have at least one valid user in the database, let's narrow down the problem. What output do you get from logging `err` and `user` in `isAuthenticated.js`? If you get `null` and `false`, what happens in the different steps in `passport.js` - are you able to find the user by e-mail address in the database and does the password match?

Do you have custom routes and controller actions or do you use the blueprints?

EDIT: Your update test would look like this with HTTP Basic Authentication:

```
describe('#update()', function(){
  it('...', function (done) {
    async.series([

      function(callback){
        request(sails.hooks.http.app)
        .post('/contact/update')
        .auth('test@test.com', 'test')
        .send({ number: 1234, mail: "test@test.com", password: "test" })
        .expect(200)
        .end(callback);
      },

      function(callback){
        request(sails.hooks.http.app)
        .post('/user/update')
        .auth('test@test.com', 'test')
        .send({ numbers: [1234], mail: "tet@test.com", password: "test" })
        .expect(200)
        .end(callback);
      }
    ], done);
  });
});
```

Comment: err is null and user is false (as you suggested). Info says 'Basic Realm="Users"'. The thing that confuses me the most is that every time I try to log something inside the the `passport.use('user-authentication', ...` function nothing happens. I use custom routes and I will post my test functions ... probably I have an error there ...

Comment: @Bruno And do you have a user in the database to log in as?

Comment: Yes I do have and I changed the policies so the new User can always be created

Comment: @Bruno Does the user creation work correctly in your tests now with your updated policy, and does the creation test pass? I see you don't have any authentication set in your tests. How about adding `.auth('test@test.com', 'test')` to your update test calls? See [supertest documentation](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#authentication).

Comment: @Bruno I don't know where the downvote came from or for what reason, but as I mentioned, your Passport.js configuration works for me in a fresh Sails.js project with the blueprint routes and controllers. And your tests work as well as long as I make the necessary adjustments for the blueprint routes and controllers (paths, methods etc.) and add the `auth()` call that I mentioned in the previous comment to the update test. If you still have authentication issues, it might be easier to find the error if you post the relevant models, controllers and routes as well.

Comment: ok thats strange why does the auth() test work but the normal ones doesn't? Or better how do I need to structure my request ?

Comment: @Bruno For `UserController.update`? If you require authentication on the server-side in your controller action through policies, you have to configure authentication on the client-side in your tests as well, using supertest's `auth()`. Just sending the username and the password as part of the request body (`send()`) doesn't perform HTTP Basic Authentication.

Comment: @Bruno Regarding your added question: you should be able to authenticate (`auth()`) and send data (`send()`) in the same request.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http) it shows you need userid and password. So looking at your code you have mail in place of userid and that is why you are getting 401 or at least where you can start looking. If you need to verify this you can look at [passport-http basic strategy here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http/blob/master/lib/passport-http/strategies/basic.js#L80).

`passport.use(new BasicStrategy(
        function(userid, password, done) {
          User.findOne({ mail: userid, password: password }, function (err, user) {
            done(err, user);
         });
       }
      ));`